# Login.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to redirect to the dashboard after login successful but it's not working. I get error something like this.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

This is my code

> login.js

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
 import LoginForm from "../Form/LoginForm";
 import {userLoggedIn} from '../../redux/actions/auth';
class Login extends Component {
    submit = data => this.props.userLoggedIn(data).then(()=> this.props.history.push("/dashboard"));
    render() {
       console.log(this.props)     <!---here when i try to log see image for result---->
        return (
            <div>
           <LoginForm submit={this.submit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, {userLoggedIn})(Login);
```

> console.log(this.props);
>   [image: login-log-image]
>
> redux/action/auth.js

```
export const userLoggedIn = (user)=> dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/login', {user})
        .then(res => {
            localStorage.redditToken = res.data.user.token;
            setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.user.token);
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOGGED_IN,
                payload: res
            })
        })
        .catch()
};
```

Comment: Can you put the code for the `userLoggedIn`? A `promise` should return to trigger `then`, but for some reason `promise` is not being returned.

Comment: @raman I have updated my question have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the `axios call` thats why its showing null. As is said in the comment above, a promise should return for `then` to work. Just return the `axios.post`.

```
export const userLoggedIn = (user) => dispatch => {
  return axios.post('/api/login', {
      user
    })
    .then(res => {
      localStorage.redditToken = res.data.user.token;
      setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.user.token);
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOGGED_IN,
        payload: res
      })
    })
    .catch()
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The error says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

that means `this.props.userLoggedIn`, which you're calling `then` on, is undefined (because your `Login` container cannot find `userLoggedIn` as a prop).

1. are you importing `userLoggedIn`?
2. see if you're following the correct mapping dispatch to action syntax with https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch